# Twilio Rest API Filtering using Coldfusion11

Tags: coldfusion, twilio, coldfusion-11

I am trying to use the following code to access the Twilio Rest API to retrieve a list of incoming calls to my twilio number for a given date range.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

```
  <cfhttp url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls" method="get" resolveurl="no" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx1">
    <cfhttpparam name="To" type="url" value="myphone">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime>=" type="url" value="2015-05-01">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime<" type="url" value="2015-06-01">
  </cfhttp>
```

When I try to connect with the above, I get a "Connection" error in coldfusion.  It doesn't like the ">".  I have also tried to put the StartTime> into a variable perform urlencodedformat() on it, but it didn't give the desired result.

When I query an individual day it works fine.

```
  <cfhttp url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls" method="get" resolveurl="no" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx1">
    <cfhttpparam name="To" type="url" value="myphone">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime" type="url" value="2015-05-01">
  </cfhttp>
```

Based off Twilio code examples (I was referencing PHP examples) it appears the the variable name can be StartTime>, StartTime>=, StartTime<, StartTime<=.

Comment: "When I rip out the 2 StartTime>= and StartTime< params and replace it with just StartTime querying 1 day it works fine". Do you mean, you only have just one cfhttpparam for StartTime. Could you append the code in your question, after ripping out StartTime>= and StartTime<

Comment: Also, can you try the below code and share the result:-

<cfhttp url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls" method="get" resolveurl="no" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx1" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam name="To" type="url" value="myphone">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime>=" type="url" value="2015-05-01">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime<" type="url" value="2015-06-01">
  </cfhttp>
  
  <cfdump var="#httpResponse#" label="httpResponse">

Comment: I've updated the question to include the working code.  I've tried StartTime> and StartTime< and each of them also came back with Connection Error.

Comment: It might be necessary to use HTML entities.  Try "&gt;" and "&lt" instead of ">" and "<".

Answer (score 1):

In you code, you are calling the "StartTime"

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls" method="get" resolveurl="no" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx1">
    <cfhttpparam name="To" type="url" value="myphone">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime>=" type="url" value="2015-05-01">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime<" type="url" value="2015-06-01">
  </cfhttp>
```

As per https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call, you should use **StartTime** & **EndTime**. I am able to dump the httpResponse with the below code:-

```
  <cfhttp url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls" method="get" resolveurl="no" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx1" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam name="To" type="url" value="myphone">
    <cfhttpparam name="StartTime" type="url" value="2015-05-01">
    <cfhttpparam name="EndTime" type="url" value="2015-06-01">
  </cfhttp>
    <cfdump var="#httpResponse#" label="httpResponse">
```

Also, https://www.twilio.com requires two SSL certificates. You need to import these to the keystore.

Comment: I will check that out tomorrow.  In this example here: they don't reference the EndTime https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-example-4  In the link you referenced EndTime is a result but not listed as a filter parameter.  I neve rhad an issue with the SSL key so their key must be recognized already.